# five table join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 5 tables so that I can create an invoice for my customers. The 5 tables are named; `Customer`, `Employee`, `Sale`, `Sale_product` and `Product`. The `Customer` and `Employee` tables are linked to the `Sale` via a one to many relationship. The `Sale` table is then linked to `Sale_product` table with a one to many relationship followed by `sale_product` being linked in the same way.

Here is my `from` statement which is giving me the problem.

```
from
INNER JOIN Sale_Product 
ON product.prod# = Sale_Product.prod#
INNER JOIN Sale 
ON sale.inv# = sale_product.inv#
INNER JOIN customer
ON customer.cust# = sale.cust#
INNER join employee
ON employee.emp# = sale.emp#
```

I would really appreciate some help understanding this.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're seeing?

Comment: SP2-0042: unknown command "from" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ON product..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ON sale.in..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ON custome..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: select sale.inv#, sale_date, 
cust_fname,cust_lname,Cust_addr,
employee.emp#, emp_fname,emp_lname
prod.prod#, mfr, prod_desc, Taxable,prod_price,qty_sold,
prod_price* qty_sold "ext_price",
(qty_sold * prod_pric)*.0725 * taxable "Sales_tax",
(prod_price *qty_sold) + (qty_sold *prod_price *.0725 *taxable) "item_amount"
from Sale_product
INNER JOIN Sale_Product 
ON product.prod# = Sale_Product.prod#
INNER JOIN Sale 
ON sale.inv# = sale_product.inv#
INNER JOIN customer
ON customer.cust# = sale.cust#
INNER join employee
ON employee.emp# = sale.emp#
where sale.inv# = &&invoce_number

Answer (score 2):

Either add a table after the "from" or remove the "inner join" before Sale_Product.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried that and it was giving me the type of error message. I would like to understand what i am doing wrong, i can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
Select * From ATable Join BTable on ATable.ID = BTable.ID
```

ie you put one of your five tables after from and then join to the other four.

Comment: So something along the lines of this? sale_product
 Join product
 on product.prod#=sale_product.prod# 
 join sale
 on sale.inv# =Sale_product.inv#
 join customer
 on customer.cust# =sale.custt#
 join employee
 on employee.emp# =sale.emp#

Comment: There has to be a from. If you were joining Customers and orders then it could be Select Customers.Name, Orders.Number From Customers Join Orders on Orders.CustomerNumber = Customers.CustomerNumber for instance

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you forgot to name the product table in your query, it belongs in the FROM clause:

```
FROM product
```